# Error : TypeError: unorderable types: float() < list()

Tags: python, minimum

I am facing this problem

```
TypeError: unorderable types: float() < list()".
```

I am using same data type then also error is coming. please help me in that.

```
i=0
min1=max(score_arr)
while(i<len(score_arr)):
    if score_arr[i] < min1:
        min1=score_arr
        i=i+1
```

Comment: `min1=score_arr` you set min1 to be a list, you cant compare it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min1 = score_arr` should be changed to `min1 = score_arr[i]`.

`min1 = score_arr` is setting `min1` to the whole list, so the next iteration fails on the line 
`if score_arr[i] < min1` since `score_arr[i]` is a float and `min1` is now a list (as indicated by the error message).

**But**, a better way to find the minimum would be `min(score_arr)` (just like you used `max` on the second line).

Comment: i have tried min() function.. but it didn't work. i don't know why.. btw thanks... i have done a silly mistake...

Comment: "i have tried min() function.. but it didn't work." Can you please elaborate?

Comment: on hacker rank platform i am doing this code but when i used min() function then no output is coming.